# My app crashes on onFocusChange() method execution end

Tags: java, android

My code gives an exception on the `onFocusChange` execution end and does not run the next lines altogether.

Here is my code:

```
final EditText discountPercent = (EditText) previewDialog.findViewById(R.id.discountPercent);
discountPercent.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
discountPercent.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            discountText = (EditText) view;
            if (discountText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                discountText.setText("0");
            }
            discountedTotal = total + total * Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(discountText.getText()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what's error exception/!

Comment: It was working file and no exception was being thrown. my bad in understanding